# how can I show date in GUI text field?

Tags: java

I'm trying to show date in a text field
this is what I did

```
java.util.Date date=new java.util.Date();
this.DateObject.setText(date);
```

But it shows error...

Comment: `setText()` takes a string parameter. You need to convert your `date` to a string.

Comment: not a complete question. trying something in swing?

Answer (score 10):

Try below code.

```
        Date now = new Date();
        //Set date format as you want
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy"); 
        this.DateObject.setText(sf.format(now));
```

Comment: @vels4j I've changed jTextField1 to DateObject.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to do a `toString` on it as

```
this.DateObject.setText(date.toString());
```